# informix ODBC stored procedure always return incorrect same value

Tags: stored-procedures, odbc, informix

I have a simple sp created in Informix

```
create procedure test(arg1 int) returning  int;
if arg1 > 1 then return 10;
else return 0;
end if;
end procedure;
```

It works as expected when called directly into Informix but when I call it from VB.NET using ODBC, it returns always 1.

Here's my vb code

```
Dim cmd As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand("{call test()}", conn)
With cmd
    .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@arg1", 0)
End With
conn.Open()
Dim dt As DataTable = New System.Data.DataTable("resultTableFromDB")
Dim da As OdbcDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter(cmd)
da.Fill(dt)
conn.Close()
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not use VB.NET but in JDBC you must show that function needs parameters with `?` char. So try `"{call test(?)}"` instead of `"{call test()}"`

**EDIT:**

I have tested your function renamed to `test_so()` and it works with JDBC-ODBC bridge from Jython. I also changed call string to retrieve result. Whole code:

```
import sys
import traceback

from java.sql import DriverManager, Types
from java.lang import Class

Class.forName("com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver")


def test_call(proc, arg1, expected):
    proc.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER)
    proc.setInt(2, arg1);
    rs = proc.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()):
        r = rs.getInt(1)
        ok = 'ok'
        if r != expected:
            ok = ' ERROR!!!'
        print('%d: %s %s' % (arg1, r, ok))


def test(db_url, usr, passwd):
    try:
        print("\n\n%s\n--------------" % (db_url))
        db = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, usr, passwd)
        proc = db.prepareCall("{ ? = call test_so(?) }");
        test_call(proc, 0, 0)
        test_call(proc, 1, 0)
        test_call(proc, 2, 10)
        test_call(proc, 10, 10)
        test_call(proc, -1, 0)
        test_call(proc, -10, 0)
        db.close()
    except:
        print("there were errors!")
        s = traceback.format_exc()
        sys.stderr.write("%s\n" % (s))


test('jdbc:odbc:MY_SYSTEM_DSN', 'USER', 'PASSWD')
```

Comment: Yes I did but same result. We are using Informix 7.3 (yes...) so could it be that it does not support sp calls? I also tried IBM.Data.Informix.dll

Comment: It worked for me with ODBC driver `3.70.TC5DE`. I used JDBC-ODBC bridge and server: `"IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.50.FC4"`