# How to get result from informix storedprocedure by jdbc?

Tags: stored-procedures, informix

I want to retrieve the result of a stored procedure in informix database, here is my code:

```
Connection connection = session.connection();
callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{? = call my_stored_procedure()}");
***callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);***
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
```

The problem is that the first `registerOutParameter` doesn't work and throws this exception:
    `java.sql.SQLException: [BEA][Informix JDBC Driver]Invalid parameter binding(s)`

What should I do ?

Comment: This will work only if your procedure have OUT parameter... something like this : `createProductDef(productname varchar(64), productdesc varchar(64),out prod_id float);`. If you want to get the RETURN, I can't tell the correct way , but what you can do is get the return of data like a select, will be something like this : `select * from table(my_stored_procedure);`

Comment: In ESQL/C, you would create a cursor on `EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_stored_procedure()`, and treat the columns as you would in a SELECT statement.  I'm not sure if that works in JDBC.

Comment: From your code it seems that there should be 3 out parameters but I think there should be only one. It would be nice to see `my_stored_procedure()` body. Have a look at other query about Informix stored procedures: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536285/informix-odbc-stored-procedure-always-return-incorrect-same-value/18545274

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you must not use `registerOutParameter()` to read function result. Instead of this you can use resultSet just like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env jython
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import sys
import traceback

from java.sql import DriverManager, Types
from java.lang import Class

Class.forName("com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver")


FUN_BODY = """CREATE FUNCTION get_ver() RETURNING VARCHAR(200);
    RETURN 'ver 1.12';
END FUNCTION;"""


def test_init(db):
    c = db.createStatement()
    try:
        c.execute('DROP FUNCTION get_ver;')
    except:
        pass
    c.execute(FUN_BODY)


def test_call(db):
    try:
        print("\n\n--------------\ncall...")
        proc = db.prepareCall("{ ? = call get_ver() }")
        rs = proc.executeQuery()
        while (rs.next()):
            r = rs.getString(1)
            print('result: %s' % (r))
    except:
        print("there were errors!")
        s = traceback.format_exc()
        sys.stderr.write("%s\n" % (s))


def test_exec(db):
    try:
        print("\n\n--------------\nEXECUTE PROCEDURE...")
        c = db.createStatement()
        rs = c.executeQuery("EXECUTE PROCEDURE get_ver()")
        while (rs.next()):
            r = rs.getString(1)
            print('result: %s' % (r))
    except:
        print("there were errors!")
        s = traceback.format_exc()
        sys.stderr.write("%s\n" % (s))


def test(db_url, usr, passwd):
    print("\n\n%s\n" % (db_url))
    db = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, usr, passwd)
    test_init(db)
    test_call(db)
    test_exec(db)
    db.close()


test('jdbc:informix-sqli://test-informix:9088/testifx:informixserver=ol_testifx;DB_LOCALE=pl_PL.CP1250;CLIENT_LOCALE=pl_PL.CP1250;charSet=CP1250', 'user', 'passwd')
test('jdbc:odbc:[system_dsn]', 'user', 'passwd')
```

My results:

```
jdbc:informix-sqli://test-informix....
--------------
call...
result: ver 1.12


--------------
EXECUTE PROCEDURE...
result: ver 1.12
```